# AngularJS: Why does two-way binding work with updates but does not allow to add or delete if the data is filtered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, filter

**If you filter data at the factory level and then bind it to a scope var,  updates work as expected (factory data is updated as well), but attempts to add or delete are not propagated to the original factory array.**

If you don't filter the factory data, two-way binding works perfectly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myDataFactory', function(){

  var factorydata = [{"a":1, "b":22}, {"a":3, "b":22}, {"a":5, "b":33}];

  return {
    FilteredData: function(b_filter){
      return factorydata.filter(function (datarow) { return datarow.b==b_filter });
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myDataFactory) {
  $scope.filtered_data = myDataFactory.FilteredData(22);

  $scope.updateFilteredData = function(){
    $scope.filtered_data[0].a = 1111111; 
  }

  $scope.spliceFilteredData = function(){
    $scope.filtered_data.splice(0,1);
  } 
  $scope.pushFilteredData = function(){
    $scope.filtered_data.push({"a":777, "b":22});
  }
});
```

Try it on codepen: http://codepen.io/ssh33/pen/NbNzxv?editors=0010

Could you please explain this behavior?

**How would you restructure the code to maintain the ability to query the factory array from the controller `myDataFactory.FilteredData(22)`, while preserving two-way binding capability (add/delete).**

Comment: _"but attempts to add or delete are not propagated to the original factory array"_ Why should they? Operate on the original array.

Comment: Array.prototype.filter creates a new object in the factory that is not related by reference to the original array, thus not updated at all.

Comment: Updates to the filtered array do update the original, so `Array.prototype.filter` must be a shallow copy.

Comment: @zeroflagL I need the ability to query the factory data: `myDataFactory.FilteredData(22)`

Comment: _"so Array.prototype.filter must be a shallow copy"_ That's exactly the reason why inserts and removals don't affect the original array and you have to apply those operations directly to it, and not to the copy. If the copy has to be updated as well, then just call `FilteredData` again.

Comment: *"then just call FilteredData again"* Could you create an answer with a code block please?